# Stripe: Preventing dunning on invoices with no credit card on file

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to handle a scenario in Stripe where a trial has ended and no credit card has been entered. Currently in Stripe...

- At the end of the trial period, an invoice is created (`invoice.created`).
- An hour later the invoice payment is attempted.
- If the attempt fails, the invoice enters dunning (per how they've been configured).

However, I would like to "short-circuit" the attempt on the invoice if there is no credit card on file. Instead of failing and entering the dunning cycle, I'd like to immediately mark the invoice as `failed` (or some other status that allows me to pay for it later).

This way...

- A customer on trial who has no intention of continuing (i.e. they never entered a credit card), will not be forced to sit through the dunning process and receive payment failure emails via Stripe.
- If they decide to come back, upon entering CC info, I could pay the outstanding invoice via the API and reactivate them on our end.

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of doing this. Specifically, while I could process an `invoice.created` webhook event and then figure out if the customer has a CC on file, I can only mark that invoice as `closed`, which, to my knowledge, means I cannot reopen it later to pay if they decide to come back.

Has anyone dealt with a scenario like this? It seems like there is no elegant scenario for handling a trial end when a customer has not entered CC info.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround. Posting here in case anyone else stumbles upon this issue one day.

Rather than short-circuiting the dunning cycle for an invoice with no CC, I simply let the dunning cycle proceed.

However, I've disabled Stripe failed payment emails from being sent from Stripe. This way, I can decide what emails to send (or not send) upon any payment failure via the webhook.

Now, when I receive an `invoice.payment_failed` hook, I can check against the customer's ID passed in the event to see if that customer has a CC. If they don't, then I can custom send a "Trial ended" email on my end and suspend the account (again, on my end).

On subsequent failures during the dunning process, I will be able to check if the account was already suspended. If so, I simply don't send any email notification.

The net effect is that a customer gets the "Trial ended" email on the first `invoice.payment_failed` event, and nothing on subsequent events.

For customers who do have a CC, I can send off a "payment failed" email on receiving each event.